# How to get the innnerhtml of a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the innerhtml of div in Jquery using `.html()` but it is not displaying anything. whereas id is not null

Comment: Could you provide us ur code sample?

Comment: `.html()` is the method you wanna use. There must be something else that is wrong. What does your HTML and selector look like?

Comment: As already said, `.html()` is the right method, hence you are using it wrongly. As we don't know *how* you use it, we cannot provide a solution. If you want help you have to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div id="HTML">mydata</div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var content = $("#HTML").html();
    alert(content);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Note that if the div appears before the script block as shown in this example then you don't need the document ready.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the DOM element hasn't loaded yet, so this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('#mydiv').html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your div exists at the time your code runs, that is, you've including the JavaScript that accesses the div in a document.ready or onload handler, and/or put the script block *after* the div in the page source, then it should work fine. E.g.,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var innerhtml = $("#idofyourdiv").html();

});
```

If you've included your JS in the head section without using a document.ready or onload handler then the div won't have been parsed yet, so jQuery won't find the element.

Answer (score 1):

you must wait for the page to be loaded ( by putting the code at the end of the page ) or using
`$(document).ready()`